# Why my cosine interpolation of a cube's face doesn't work?

Tags: rendering, 3d, interpolation, drawing

**NB please :** executable use cases are available at the end of this question. I begin this question by showing you the problems of my program, then I explain how the latter works, and finally I end up with these both executable use cases.

## What I want to do

I want to draw the bottom face of a cube. To do that, I interpolate between the 4 vertices of this face. I use two kinds of interpolation :

1. Linear
2. Cosine

*I know it's typically the aim of GPUs, but I wanted to implement it myself to learn and try the "deep" mechanisms of 3D rendering.*

## Results

Each point of the following both pictures are interpolated between the 4 vertices of the bottom face (except the 8 vertices of my cube).

### With linear interpolation

It's OK, no problem.

[image]

### With cosine interpolation

Error. As you can see, there is some weird problem : face's points are inclined towards left.

[image]

## How do I interpolate between 4 points ?

I test all the combinations of interpolation's weights and, if the sum of the weights equals 1, I draw the resulting point. *I know this method is not very good (a lot of consumption of CPU and RAM), and there are `P` duplicates. But this problem is (1) secondary and (2) out of the range of this StackOverflow question.*

In other words : the definition of the interpolation between 4 points is : `P = aA + bB + cC + dD`. `a + b + c + d` must equals 1 to draw `P`, otherwise it's not drawn. `(a;b;c;d) \in [0;1]^4` by the way.

A concrete example is (step = 1) :

`P = 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d` is NOT drawn

`P = 0a + 0b + 0c + 1d` is drawn

`P = 0a + 0b + 1c + 0d` is drawn

`P = 0a + 0b + 1c + 1d` is NOT drawn

etc. ("I test all the combinations"). (Last is : `P = 1a + 1b + 1c + 1d`, which is not drawn).

To test all these combinations, I iterates on the weights, with a step, using recursion.

### Case of the linear interpolation

The above definition doesn't change : `P = aA + bB + cC + dD`.

### Case of the cosine interpolation

The above definition does change : `P = aA + bB + cC + dD` becomes `P = a'A + b'B + c'C + d'D`, with : `a' = 0.5(1 - cos(a * \pi))` and the idea is the same for the three other weights.

*This new definition is not random, I could explain how I found it, but it's out of the range of this topic (in résumé : a simple remap of the cosine function).*

## Question

Why does it works well with the linear interpolation, and not the cosine one ? Indeed, the cosine face's points are inclined towards left.

## By the way : interpolations between two points work well

Linear and cosine interpolations both work very well when used between two points, as you can see below.

### Linear interpolation

It's OK, no problem.

[image]

### Cosine interpolation

It's OK, no problem.

[image]

## Implementation and Executable

I wrote the program in Scala. First I show you the functions, then two use cases you can execute along with the given functions.

### Tests all the combinations of interpolations between `n` points of `k` coordinates

```
def computeAllPossibleInterpolatedPoints(step : Double, points : Seq[Seq[Double]], transform: (Double) => Double) : Seq[Seq[Double]] = {
  var returned_object : Seq[Seq[Double]] = Seq.empty[Seq[Double]]
  recursiveInterpolation(0, Seq.empty[Double])

  def recursiveInterpolation(current_weight_id : Int, building_weights : Seq[Double]) : Unit = {

    (.0 to 1.0 by step).foreach(current_step => {
      if (current_weight_id < points.size - 1) {
        recursiveInterpolation(current_weight_id + 1, building_weights :+ current_step)
      } else {
        val found_solution = building_weights :+ current_step
        if(BigDecimal(found_solution.sum).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble == 1.0) {
          returned_object = returned_object :+ interpolation(found_solution, points, transform)
        }
      }
    })
  }

  returned_object
}
```

### Interpolates between `n` points of `k` coordinates

```
def interpolation(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]], transform: (Double) => Double) : Seq[Double] = {
  if(BigDecimal(weights.sum).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble != 1) {
    println("ERROR : `SUM(weights) != 1`. Returning `null`.")
    return null
  }
  if(weights.exists(weight => BigDecimal(weight).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble < 0)
    ||
    weights.exists(weight => BigDecimal(weight).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble > 1)) {
    println("ERROR : `EXISTS(weight) / weight < -1 OR weight > 1`. Returning `null`.")
    return null
  }

  weights.map(transform).zip(points).map(
    weight_point => weight_point._2.map(coordinate => weight_point._1 * coordinate)
  ).reduce((point_a : Seq[Double], point_b : Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2))
}
```

### Interpolation functions

```
def linear(weight : Double) : Double = {
  weight
}

def cosine(weight : Double) : Double = {
  (1 - Math.cos(weight * Math.PI)) * 0.5
}
```

### Two use cases : between 2 points, each made of 2 coordinates (first use case : linear interpolation, second use case : cosine interpolation)

Note that you can add 2 new points to each of the following functions, to interpolate a face instead of a segment (for now, the below code indeed interpolates points of a segment).

```
val interpolated_points : Seq[Seq[Int]] = interpolator.computeAllPossibleInterpolatedPoints(0.05, Seq(Seq(22, 22), Seq(33, 33)), interpolator.linear).map(_.map(_.intValue()))

val interpolated_points : Seq[Seq[Int]] = interpolator.computeAllPossibleInterpolatedPoints(0.05, Seq(Seq(22, 22), Seq(33, 33)), interpolator.cosine).map(_.map(_.intValue()))
```